# How to allocate Irregular area as ContentPresenter?

Tags: wpf, contentpresenter

If we have a grid with 2 columns/1 row, we can have [something like in  this blog](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155211/Building-a-control-template-style-for-the-tabContr).

But if we have 2 columns/2 rows [that means - main sqaure is divided into 4 small sqaures]...and only square at row-1,column-0 should conains tabs..and other three small area should be content presenter, what to do for that?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No control is designed to fit into such a shape (and the Grid is not designed to host such controls either), i would not recommend to try anything like this.

Comment: Can we use a polygon for this ?

Comment: @Relativity: How do you expect any of this to work? If you have a non-rectangular area you need to create your own panel to provide layout for the content, some shape will not be enough.

Comment: Hi...Can I have something like this -> A grid with two columns...first column have width-50..and have a floating expander in that. This column will contain all main tabs. Second column will have aall sub tabs...Again control template for second column will divide it into two columns...first column as subtabs...and second column as contents.

Comment: @Relativity: This does not sound like what you asked for in your question even though i cannot exactly imagine it. As long as you are only dealing with rectanglular areas it should be possible with built in controls...